# Remove edit option from joomla website

Tags: php, joomla

I am new in joomla and i am developing one website in joomla.
I am using the articles for some pages.
Now i have seen that in my website in all most place there is one option is there for modification content from website.
How can i hide or remove that edit option?

Please see below image for that option.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This edit option is actually module editing.

You can disable it from Joomla **global configuration**.
There is a setting **Mouse-over edit icons** in set it to **None** to remove this.

Comment: I have set it but i have only removed from menu.
I am still able to see in content.

Answer (score 0):

This is by default, only available to the admins of the site, so I wouldn't be too worried about it. Alternatively the easiest is to go to System Global Configuration > Mouse-over edit icons and set to none.

Comment: I have set it but i have only removed from menu. I am still able to see that edit option in content.